# DateTime.ToString can return different results for same format specifier

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a problem with 'd' specifier in DateTime format string. MSDN [says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dSpecifier):

> The "d" custom format specifier represents the day of the month as a number from 1 through 31. A single-digit day is formatted without a leading zero.

If I use this format specifier with other symbols in format string the result will be correct:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 1, 2, 6, 30, 15);
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("d ")); //with space after 'd'
//displays: 2
```

but if I remove space from this sample

```
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("d"));
```

the result becomes to `"1/2/2008".`

Why result string depends on format string length? And how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because as a single character, it behaves as [The `"d"` standard format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ShortDate) which returns [`ShortDatePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern) of the `CurrentCulture` (looks like it is `M/d/yyyy` for your settings) but with space, it behaves as [The `"d"` custom format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dSpecifier) which returns day numbers without leading zero for single digit days.

From [The `"d"` Custom Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dSpecifier)

> **If the `"d"` format specifier is used without other custom format
>   specifiers**, it is interpreted as [The `"d"` standard date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ShortDate)
>   specifier. For more information about using a single format specifier,
>   see [Using Single Custom Format Specifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers) later in this topic.

And from Using Single Custom Format Specifiers

> **A custom date and time format string consists of two or more
>   characters**. Date and time formatting methods interpret any
>   single-character string as a standard date and time format string. If
>   they do not recognize the character as a valid format specifier, they
>   throw a `FormatException`. For example, a format string that consists
>   only of the specifier "h" is interpreted as a standard date and time
>   format string. However, in this particular case, an exception is
>   thrown because there is no "h" standard date and time format
>   specifier.
>
> To use any of the custom date and time format specifiers as the only
>   specifier in a format string (that is, to use the **"d"**, "f", "F", "g",
>   "h", "H", "K", "m", "M", "s", "t", "y", "z", ":", or "/" custom format
>   specifier by itself), **include a space before or after the specifier,
>   or include a percent ("%") format specifier before the single custom
>   date and time specifier**.

Answer (score 0):

well you can avoid this issue using the `Day` properties in the `DateTime` class

```
Console.WriteLine(date1.Day.ToString());
```