# DateTime.ParseExact using just hour format not working

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-core

In my net core project I have to parse a string into a DateTime. The format is dynamic and not known at compilation time. The code is:

```
var datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(data, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

but I'm having issues when the format is just the hour and is coming as numbers from 0 to 23. According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) article to specify the hour format you have 4 options: *h*, *hh*, *H* and *HH*, but when trying to parse "0"

Using *h* I get:

> System.FormatException : Input string was not in a correct format.

Using *hh* I get:

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Using *H* I get:

> System.FormatException : Input string was not in a correct format.

Using *HH* I get:

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

In [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) article it is stated that

> If format is a custom format pattern that does not include date or
>   time separators (such as "yyyyMMddHHmm"), use the invariant culture
>   for the provider parameter and the widest form of each custom format
>   specifier. For example, if you want to specify hours in the format
>   pattern, specify the wider form, "HH", instead of the narrower form,
>   "H".

but it is what i have been doing and is not working. I cannot guess how to achieve parsing a string which is just the hour into a DateTime. Any ideas??

**EDIT**

The exception is thrown when executing any of these lines:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("0", "HH", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
DateTime.ParseExact("0", "H", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

I cannot use TimeSpan.Parse as I have a generic solution to read *xlsx* files. How to read the file is stored on the datatabase. Sometimes the DateTime is all in one column and the format is `ddMMyyHHmmss` and others the DateTime is in one column with the format `ddMMyy` and the hour in other as a number from 0 to 23 (minutes and seconds should be initialized with 0). Later the date and hour are merged to return the whole DateTime.

Comment: What will be the date in case you only have time, would it be 1.1.0001?

Comment: In that case the day part will be ignored, so it's the same.

Comment: May be you already checked this, but here it is anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321486/how-to-convert-time-only-using-datetime-parse?rq=1

Comment: Also, is it an option for you to check what value you have and pad it, so it fits a proper format, e.g. if string.Length == 1 or 2...string = string + ":00".

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Unfortunately, `DateTime.ParseExact` doesn't handle *all* format combinations, and a string that contains just 1 number, taken to mean the hour, isn't handled. The most likely reason for this is that "nobody" would ask `DateTime.ParseExact` to parse something that isn't a date or a time or a combination, and `"23"` is neither.

Comment: if you do not need the day, you certainly do not need a `DateTime`

Comment: As I have a generic solution I cannot know beforehand if it will be a complete DateTime or just the date or just the time. If not the solution would be quite simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When supplying only a single character as a format, it will be interpreted as a [*standard* format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) rather than a [*custom* format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).  The `%` character can be used to force it to be treated as a custom specifier.  This is covered in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#UsingSingleSpecifiers).

Thus, instead of passing `"h"`, pass `"%h"`.  Instead of `"H"`, pass `"%H"`

Other answers, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35520706/634824), have mentioned this with regards to formatting using `String.Format` or `ToString`, but it is also applicable for `ParseExact`.

Alternatively, you may find your code more legible and performant if you instead start with some known `DateTime` value (perhaps `DateTime.MinValue`, or perhaps something else) and then use `AddHours` to get to the desired result.  (Of course, you would parse the string to an integer first.)

Comment: I didn't know that difference between standard and costume formats specifiers. Your answer fix my problem. Thanks!!